# Should review ban on SO also ban you from reviewing on Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-suspension

I was recently review banned on SO (admittedly, I did deserve it), but for the length of my review ban on SO I was still allowed to do reviews here. It got me thinking: Shouldn't someone who has a review ban in SO also have one here? With this now being the Meta site for only Stack Overflow, should some of the penalties also carry over here as well?

Comment: You might be completely wrong about everything you review on SO about c# but here on MSO you're master of the [tag:review-suspension] so I would say: No, they are different things, so require separate penalties.....

Comment: While this site is the meta for SO, the two work independently to eachother for most things.

Answer (score 4):

Considering that more questions get posted in 15 minutes on SO than in 24 hours on meta.SO, I'd say it's really not worth programming it to have review-suspensions, flag-bans, etc carried over to the meta site. Meta.SO is the most active meta I think, so the same definitely holds true for other sites across the network.

So imo, it's not worth it to ban users from reviewing on meta.SO, because they would likely only be missing out on 5 or so reviews per day. No point in kicking them when they're down.