# Can we be banned from meta reviews? If yes, will I be banned from reviews on the main site?

Tags: support, review-queues, meta, review-suspension

I like reviewing very much but I often fail audits because they are so hard! So now I tend to review the "easy" ones like Triage. Because it is pretty obvious which options to choose.

Recently I got to 2k reputation and am able to do meta reviews. I am afraid that I will be banned again and I cannot get the steward badge on the main site. So can I be banned from reviewing on meta? I guess yes. But is this ban independent from the ban on the main site? i.e. can I still review on the main site if I was banned on the meta site?

Comment: You won't be able to review on meta until you have at least 3k rep, and the suggested edits queue on Meta [will be always empty](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276226/review-link-in-navigation-bar-shouldnt-appear-on-meta-at-500-rep) until you reach 5k.

Comment: 1) If you're not sure about what to do, `Skip` is always the right choice. 2) Audits are supposed to be hard. If you're failing a lot, look through your history and see when your opinion doesn't match the other triage reviewers. (Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/9810615) review for example). 3) The last [audit failure](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9721061) is on an edit that added nonsensical rambling to the question (including the code) but you clicked approve.

Comment: Edit suggestion audits are NOT hard -- while some of the other queues use real content that the original reviewers might have made a mistake on, suggested edit audits are constructed to be absolutely and indisputably bad.  theB is sugar-coating the failure he linked to -- stringing together a bunch of words and acronyms is not "rambling" (which requires valid sentences that make sense but never really make a useful point), this was actual gibberish.  As was the code change.  If you really clicked "Accept" on that audit, you deserve a ban.  Just stay out of the review queues until you're more

Comment: familiar with what good content looks like.

Comment: Also, stop thinking about the steward badge as something you're entitled to receive.

Comment: Here's another (non-audit) example where you reviewed wrongly: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9708281

Comment: @theB Audits are not supposed to be hard.  Some are but most of the time you are supposed to be able to spot the audit as the audit is more to make sure you are looking at the post than picking the right action.

Comment: *"So now I tend to review the "easy" ones like Triage."* ... let me guess, you often click "Should be improved"/"Requires editing"?

Comment: if you think audits are *hard* you are probably trying to judge things that are out of your bailiwick. If you do not know Perl, always skip Perl questions. Or better yet, filter on only what you do know. From my experience over the years, audits tend to be of the *"are you paying attention"* category. I have to agree with @BenVoigt on this one. If you are getting banned then you are doing something to deserve it.

Comment: I think thats a strong example of how things can go wrong in self-moderated communities. Guys like Sweeper focusing only on getting as much rep and badges as possible, performing whatever actions on whatever topics they have no clue. Ends up with shitty content and poor moderation. I am pretty amazed Stack Overflow is still strong enough to  defend its quality and prevent people like Sweeper from getting too far and too powerful within the community.
Sweeper - just get better on the topic you're trying to deal with, focus on adding value and the badges and rep will come with time (or not).

Comment: @Amu: No, don't "just take it easy bro". Audits are there to help maintain the quality of the site, and blasting through regardless when you're aware that you're getting it wrong is irresponsible, whether intentional or not. The OP did the right thing by asking.

Comment: @theB: I'm confused. Was that ever an actual edit?

Comment: @NathanOliver - I cut short that sentence because when I first wrote it the comment came across very mean.  I'm trying not to be mean. (Original sentence: "Audits are supposed to be hard _for careless reviewers._")

Comment: Make a habit of opening the question in a separate tab on every review. You'll be able to spot audits easily that way because what the review page shows you won't match up to the real question. Review everything in context before making a choice. It might also help to add a tag filter to the languages/technologies you're familiar with. Never be afraid to Skip if you aren't sure what to do.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't know if Meta even has review audits, so you may not be able to be banned here, but the two sites are independent.  [A ban on the main site wouldn't stop you from reviewing on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280968/should-review-ban-on-so-also-ban-you-from-reviewing-on-meta-stack-overflow)  I imagine the opposite would also be true.

However anything you review here would only count towards a Meta badge, so you couldn't review here in an attempt to earn badges for the main site.

You'll find plenty of answers on Meta that will give you advice about how to be a better reviewer.

In my limited experience, it takes time to learn the intricacies about reviewing, and to learn how to properly review.  Even the "easy" ones can be improperly reviewed, so it's important to slow down and make sure you really appreciate the right response for a review, regardless of whether it's an audit.

Comment: There are meta reviews. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review will take you there (if you have sufficient privileges).

Comment: @DavidPostill Right! But are there audits?

Comment: There's only Close, Reopen and Suggested Edits

Comment: Note that moderators can manually impose suspensions even without audits. As far as I can tell, that functionality exists on meta sites (i.e., I can go through the flow up to the point where I'd actually impose the suspension), though I've never actually tried to impose one on meta.

Answer (score 44):

If you really do find audits "so hard", something is wrong here. It suggests that you actually find *all* reviewing hard, but you're only aware of the audits case because of the immediate feedback.

**I worry that if you find the audits so hard, you are probably accepting bad edits.**

It may be time to stop reviewing, and spend some time studying the criteria for a good edit. Otherwise, what's the point of the audits?

For example, how on earth could you have believed that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9721061) would be a valid edit?

However, I don't see much other evidence in your profile of accepting bad edits, which makes me wonder whether you're just hitting "Accept" on all of them and getting lucky. *That's what audits are designed to stop*. Pay more attention to what you're reviewing, and you'll be fine… or don't review!

Comment: Is it possible to be banned from Meta reviews?  I haven't encountered any audits on Meta (although as an <5k reviewer, I've only done a limited number of Close and Reopen reviews).