# How about an "I Disagree" button to flag a bad audit question?

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

**No, this is not a duplicate.**  The original post below acknowledges the other question and differentiates it from this one.  The irony here is that this could now end up as an audit question to make sure people are paying attention.

**Original Post:**

When reviewing closed questions, there are occasional "audit" questions that are supposed to make sure you're paying attention.  The problem with these is that sometimes you can "fail" these audits, not because you weren't paying attention, but because you disagree with how the audited question was originally moderated.

What if there a way to flag an audit question besides creating a meta question?

Right now the review process requires you to click an "I Understand" button.  Suppose there also was "I Disagree" button?  So far, this is similar to [this other proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295960/add-an-i-dont-understand-or-i-disagree-button-after-failing-an-audit), but what if you had to support your position by writing some text before you could move on?

The tone of the UI when you "fail" an audit is extremely off-putting, and makes me far less likely to participate in the review process.  Being told to slow down and pay attention--after you've studied the question for a few minutes, reviewed the comments, and looked up terminology because the question is outside a domain you know--is borderline abusive.

I refuse to click "I Understand" in these cases, and generally go upvote the question, vote to re-open it, and add a comment explaining why I think the closing was unfair.  It seems it would be far more productive to flag the question and dubious for audits and encourage the reviewer to review more questions.

Comment: *So far, this is similar to this other proposal, but what if you had to support your position by writing some text before you could move on?* This is the crux of your question, so let's be fair: `hlsdkjfqlkhefvqch`

Comment: Citing Brad: "[*Rather than an "I don't understand" button, I could get behind a "This audit is incorrect" one that required you to type an explanation for why you disagreed (with a minimum character limit).*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188790/257849)" Though that's already past 6-8 months...

Comment: similar to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button

Comment: I would take care a little since you've taken the path of being offended by the tone of a piece of generic text. You know that there are piss-poor reasons to fail audits and should be able to just dismiss that garbage text when that happens, the fact that you can't/won't is maybe a sign that there is something brewing. Review burn-out perhaps. I'm not pretending to be a psychologist here, I base that on what I've seen in other metas where people go on the war path against the audit fail page.

Comment: @Gimby: For what it's worth, the audit fail text really is quite inflammatory. It's not surprising that anyone who fails an audit for a lousy reason would find this aggravating or even infuriating. Just because one should be capable of ignoring the sharp rebukes of foolish people (and audits are sometimes exactly that) doesn't mean they're fun to hear.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I agree it is garbage, I don't agree that should invoke any kind of emotional response ;) But I've been down that path before, even with a rather provocative answer. Right now I want to go no further than just tip the hat that this may be a sign of something else.

Comment: Not a duplicate of the other thread, as I _explicitly_ pointed out in the original post.

Comment: *The irony here is that this could now end up as an audit question to make sure people are paying attention.* [SO would have to implement meta review audits, before that could happen](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307852/4151918).

Comment: @Gimby:  When a user does the right thing, and then is chastised for not doing the right thing, and is then expected to click a button that states the user agrees that he/she did the wrong thing, an emotional response is normal, appropriate, and expected.  It's bad a design that doesn't show proper respect the user.

Comment: I rather wonder what happened to the disputed audits? Are they still online or are they deleted by now? After all reporting bad audits on Meta might already solve at least half of the problem. I would not feel so bad pressing "I understand" once if I could afterwards help removing this particular audit on Meta.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy that's only you using the word "chastised" where you shouldn't. No, its a piece of text, not a person speaking to you. Let it go.

Comment: @Gimby:  The text says, "STOP! Look and Listen.  This was an audit designed to see if you were paying attention.  **You didn't pass.** ..." [caps and emphasis in original] You're fooling yourself if you don't think this is an example of chastising.